# Equações em módulo

Tags: javascript, matemática

Preciso pegar a altura de 2 elementos, onde estes elementos podem ter alturas variadas e então encontrar a diferença entre a altura dos mesmos como no exemplo:

**A** = 20
**B** = 15

|**A** - **B**| = 5

Como faço isso em uma equação com JS?

Comment: Você já tentou fazer alguma coisa? Tem algum problema específico?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Se entendi corretamente sua pergunta, seria algo assim:

```
function getAbsDiff(A, B)
{
   return Math.abs(A - B);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seria apenas isso? Poderia ser mais claro por gentileza?

```
$('.elemento-1').height() - $('.elemento-2').height()
```

Comment: Encontrei na net. Usando a função Math.abs eu consigo retirar a diferença entre as duas `div`, mas é praticamente o que está acima @Diego

Comment: Compreendido ^^

Answer (score 0):

Aqui está a solução que encontrei:

http://jsfiddle.net/leandroluk/6X7Ve/1/

Comment: ou seja: a resposta do Lucas está correta, certo? Basta passar a altura dos elementos como parâmetro para a função mostrada na resposta. É legal você experimentar a resposta dele e talvez marcá-la como aceita, já que é essencialmente a mesma coisa que está no seu fiddle. Valorize as pessoas que deram atenção à sua pergunta. =)

Comment: Correto @elias, para falar a verdade não cheguei a ver o post dele, talvez tenha faltado um F5 na página. agora sim que li e já marquei como aceita.